# drawing the region of the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

supposes z was a complex number

how would I go about drawing the complex plane for which 
$(iz-1)/(z-i)$ is real.

I have drawn the plane, by using intuition, where I claimed the real part is 0 and the imaginary part is -1. but I have no way to prove how I arrived at my answer.

at this point I am completely stuck.

Comment: Can you make the denominator real?  (Try multiplying your fraction by the "fancy form of 1": $\frac{z+\mathrm{i}}{z+\mathrm{i}}$.)  Then you only need to find when the resulting numerator is real (which is a bit easier).

Comment: hmm..i see what you mean, still not very helpful, as I am still a little confused

Comment: If you break $z$ into its real and imaginary parts, can you find the real and imaginary parts of the resulting numerator?

Comment: i guess...i think -1 and 0  are the real and imaginary for the  numerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = x + \mathrm{i}y$ for real $x$ and $y$, otherwise we have no hope of graphing anything.  Then $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{i}z - 1}{z - \mathrm{i}} &= \frac{\mathrm{i}(x + \mathrm{i} y) - 1}{(x + \mathrm{i} y) - \mathrm{i}} \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{i}x - (y + 1)}{x + \mathrm{i} (y-1)} \cdot \frac{x - \mathrm{i} (y-1)}{x - \mathrm{i} (y-1)} \\
    &= \frac{-2x + \mathrm{i}(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2 + (y-1)^2} . \\
\end{align*}$$

The denominator is real, so the fraction is real when the numerator is real.  The numerator is real when its imaginary part is zero.  Its imaginary part is $x^2+y^2-1$.  Setting this equal to zero, we wish to plot $x^2+y^2 = 1$, which we recognize as the unit circle.