# proving complex numbers given an equation to satisfy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

how would I go by proving that

if $a$,$b$ and $z$ are complex numbers and z satisfies

$|z-a| = |z-b|$

then there exists complex numbers a, w and a real number x so that

$\bar{w}z+w\bar{z} = x$

the first $w$ and second $z$ have a line on top, I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: How much of your homework will you be posting today?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545437/drawing-the-region-of-the-complex-plane

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  This frequently help see what's "really going on".  For instance, your first equation is the set of points equidistant from $a$ and $b$ (the perpendicular bisector of the line segment between $a$ and $b$).

Comment: Do you know that $\overline{z}$ means "the complex conjugate of $z$"?

Comment: just the 2 I couldn't do. They are not homework...practice questions

Comment: This one is definitely not homework. I can't say the same for the other ones :)